# custom autoscroll top directive in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

When changing route, the new loaded page is not scrolled to the top.  I have added the `autoscroll = true` directive in the ui-view element, but it's not scrolled all the way to the top, maybe there is an offset 50px down, I think it's got to do w/ the top fixed navigation bar.

I added a custom scroll directive, which does the job, the new page is scrolled to the top.  The only obstacle I have this directive is not letting me scroll down.  I'm not familiar with directives and I know for sure there is more code missing in the custom directive.  Can anybody help me with this?

Here is the directive:

```
angular.module('myapp')
.directive("scrollTop", function ($window) {
return function(scope, element, attrs) {

angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
    scope.visible = false;
    $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    scope.$apply();
});

};
});
```

Here is the html code:

```
<body id="myapp" ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-include="'navbar/_navbar.html'" ng-controller="NavbarMenuCtrl"></div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div ui-view scroll-top><%= yield %></div ui-view>
  </div>
  <div ng-include="'footer/_footer.html'"></div>
</body>
```

I wished I could use that `autoscroll` directive, but there is a tiny offset, it's almost scrolled to the top.  Maybe I can work around that directive instead of building a custom one.  I appreciate your help, still a newbie in AngularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `autoscroll` is used to scroll to the top of the `ui-view` element when the view is updated. So if you would like to scroll the whole window whenever there is a state change.You may just add an run block to watch the state change and scroll it.

```
angular.module('myapp').run(['$rootScope','$window',function($rootScope,$window){
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess",function(){
         $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    })
}]);
```